# Как переменной String присвоить значение matcher.group() класса java.util.regex?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Суть проблемы, в своем проекте приходится использовать регулярные выражения, т.к. я новичок в программирование решил загуглить, что это такое и с чем его едят) Наткнулся на вот эту статью:[habrahabr.ru](http://habrahabr.ru/post/260773/) где нашел решение для своего проекта,  но вот как переменной String присвоить значение matcher.group() разобраться не могу. Вот основа кода взятая из статьи:

```
 // IP адрес
String regexp = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
// для сравнения работы find() и matches()
String goodIp = "192.168.0.3";
String badIp = "192.168.0.3g";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(goodIp);
// matches() - true, find() - true
matcher = pattern.matcher(badIp);
// matches() - false, find() - true
// а теперь получим дополнительную информацию
System.out.println(matcher.find() ?
        "I found '"+matcher.group()+"' starting at index "+matcher.start()+" and ending at index "+matcher.end()+"." : "I found nothing!");`
// I found the text '192.168.0.3' starting at index 0 and ending at index 11.
```

Вот основа кода взятая из статьи;

Вот такой вариант:
String teg = matcher.group();
не подходит при компиляции выдает ошибку, поэтому как дальше использовать данные matcher.group() я не знаю, может кто ни будь подсказать?

Comment: Используйте блок if/while и там значение присваивайте. См. [пример кода](https://ideone.com/gvL4sB). В выражении просто надо двойной обратный слеш использовать.

Comment: результат демо Вас устраивает? Опубликовать ответ?

Comment: Благодарю, все предельно понятно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java необходимо использовать двойной обратный слеш для экранирования специальных символов. Значение, полученное в результате нахождения совпадения, нужно присваивать переменной внутри блока `if/while`.

Вот рабочий пример:

```
String regexp = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
//                                                          ^^ - двойной обратный слеш 
String goodIp = "192.168.0.3";
String badIp = "192.168.0.3g";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(goodIp);
String teg1 = "";
String teg2 = "";
if (matcher.find())
{
    teg1 = matcher.group();  // присваиваем значение teg1
    System.out.println(teg1);
}
matcher = pattern.matcher(badIp);
if (matcher.find())
{
    teg2 = matcher.group();  // присваиваем значение teg2
    System.out.println(teg2);
}
```

[См. демо](https://ideone.com/gvL4sB)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Ваш ответ, помог решить мою проблему.